# PHP-MySQL Query to display rows of one table with priority

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I wonder if there is a query (PHP + MySQL code), for having the following rows in my table:

```
    id name    featured
    ----------------
    1 Robert   0
    2 John     1
    3 Pax      1
    4 Max      0
    5 Emily    0
    6 Sara     0
    7 Estella  0
```

Shows the following in my page (with priority of featured column value and order by ASC to accommodate the remaining):

```
    id name    featured
    ----------------
    2 John     1
    3 Pax      1
    1 Robert   0
    4 Max      0
    5 Emily    0
    6 Sara     0
    7 Estella  0
```

This is my actual code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY id desc';
```

I hope someone help me, I do not find something similar in Google :/

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY featured desc';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first order by `featured` column and then order by `id`

```
SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY featured DESC, id ASC
```

Output:

```
| id |    name | featured |
|----|---------|----------|
|  2 |    John |        1 |
|  3 |     Pax |        1 |
|  1 |  Robert |        0 |
|  4 |     Max |        0 |
|  5 |   Emily |        0 |
|  6 |    Sara |        0 |
|  7 | Estella |        0 |
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38c87b/1)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY featured desc, id asc
```